# Playback of videos on Apple TV - not airshare

Tags: apple

I would like recommendations for the best way to playback personal home videos on Apple TV without having to upload them to Vimeo or YouTube privately, then play them back.

I do not want to AirShare them, as this often results in buffering, dropped frames, or lower video quality. I'd like to be able to play a video in full quality from the Apple TV directly.

Vimeo used to enable this option, but they are soon going to stop supporting Apple TV's TVos, so I'm looking for other alternatives.

I don't want the videos to be publicly visible on the internet.